# Why copying stringstream is not allowed?

Tags: c++, stringstream

```
int main()
{
   std::stringstream s1("This is my string.");
   std::stringstream s2 = s1; // error, copying not allowed
}
```

I couldn't find a reason as to why i can't copy stringstream. could you provide some reference?

Comment: In case you are not aware of this, you can effectively achieve a copy using `std::stringstream s2(s1.str());`.

Comment: @Space: I think this would be more appropriate: `std::stringstream s2; s2 << s1.rdbuf();`.

Comment: @GManNickG Doesn't this has a lower performance?

Comment: @StanE: Than...what? Than the previous comment? I don't think so. You'd need to measure to be sure.

Comment: @GManNickG Yes, your example with the shift operator compared to the constructor version from previous comment. I just ask because I'm new to this and I'm interested to know if the performance is different. I would think that using the contructor might be faster, since there is no conversion for different types and space must be allocated only once, etc. But I'm not sure. Just interested to know.

Comment: @StanE: The only way to be sure is to measure. :)

Answer (score 89):

Copying of ANY stream in C++ is disabled by having made the copy constructor `private`.

Any means ANY, whether it is `stringstream`, `istream`, `ostream`,`iostream` or whatever.

Copying of *stream* is disabled because it doesn't make sense. Its very very very important to understand what *stream* means, to actually understand why copying *stream* does not make sense. `stream` is not a container that you can make copy of. It doesn't contain data.

If a list/vector/map or any container is a bucket, then stream is a hose through which data *flows*. Think of stream as some pipe *through* which you get data; a pipe -  at one side is the source (sender), on the other side is the sink (receiver). That is called unidirectional stream. There're also bidirectional streams through which data *flows* in both direction. So what does it make sense making a copy of such a thing? It doesn't contain any data at all. It is *through* which you get data.

Now suppose for a while if making a copy of stream is allowed, and you created a *copy* of `std::cin` which is in fact input stream. Say the copied object is `copy_cin`. Now ask yourself : does it make sense to read data from `copy_cin` stream when the very same data has already been read from `std::cin.` No, it doesn't make sense, because the user entered the data only once, the keyboard (or the input device) generated  the electric signals only once and they flowed through all other hardwares and low-level APIs only once. How can your program read it *twice or more*?

Hence, creating *copy* is not allowed, but creating *reference* is allowed:

```
std::istream  copy_cin = std::cin; //error
std::istream & ref_cin = std::cin; //ok
```

Also note that you can create another instance of stream and can make it use the same *underlying buffer* which the old stream is currently using. See this : https://ideone.com/rijov

Comment: @Nawaz - Any reason for making the copy constructor **private** ?

Comment: @Mahesh: Yes. Let me explain it in the answer itself.

Comment: @Mahesh: Now read the edited answer. Now it explains this in detail.

Comment: will 2 streams sharing the same buffer have an independent state (e.g. current position)? In other words, is the state a property of the buffer or a stream? Both ways seem awkward: 1) independent state - suppose one stream consumed the whole buffer and needs a "refill" while the other did not; 2) shared state - seems like both streams tear pieces of data from each other hands. So I don't see what it can be useful for

Comment: @davka: The buffer is of course shared. Read from one and it will be missing from the other.

Comment: The 'hose' metaphor is nice, but then where is that data that I put into a std::stringstream ending up then? There must be a default bucket connected to that hose, as I can get the content of that bucket by doing a e.g. std::stringstream::str().

Comment: @Chaos_99: It is the other end which is receiving (or rather reading) from the stream, e.g in the context of *input* stream, an operation like `std::cin >> data` describes the receiving end.

Comment: I don't see how anything you say is different for iterators and streams, yet you can copy iterators but not streams.

Comment: @Mehrdad: The design of iterators is based on pointer-semantic (pointers are iterators, remember?). That is why iterators are copyable because pointers are copyable! You can still selectively disable copy for iterators of certain category (say input iterators), but that would introduce complexity and inconsistency to the design. for example, random access iterators (such as pointers) are input iterator too.

Comment: I understand perfectly why iterators are copyable, I'm not asking or complaining about that. I'm saying that streams could be copyable in exactly the same way with exactly the same result, yet they aren't... which means your answer is probably wrong because there's no real reason why they couldn't have the same semantics as pointers upon copying.

Comment: @Mehrdad: The answer is same: to avoid (unnecessary) complexity. Not convinced? Try to implement your own copyable stream classes.

Comment: @Nawaz: Uh, no, it's not "the same". Saying it's *"to avoid complexity"* is ***very*** different from saying *"it doesn't make sense"*. If you now realized it *does* make sense (and it seems you did), then it's worth changing your answer, because currently it's wrong -- it *does* make sense, it's just not as easy to implement as for iterators.

Comment: @Mehrdad: I've to prove the complexity in order to say it. Moreover, the name *stream*  is so chosen because it acts like it, in which case, *copy* indeed doesn't make sense. Both are true at the same time. "Water is usually liquid" doesn't contradict "it is H2O".

Comment: .... Also, remember that, *first* it doesn't make sense if you go by its name (and how it behaves), then comes the complexity factor (which is not worth adding). Copyable iterator also doesn't make much sense, because it does NOT really copy. it is supported anyway, because pointers intrinsically support it (so in this case, not supporting it adds complexity and inconsistency). Hope that makes sense now.

Comment: Honestly it's not as ridiculous of an idea as you make it seem, but I don't have any way to convince you so...

Comment: One way to copy a stream like cin would to have them all have independent iterators to a shared list of received input. I don't see another way because a single copy may undecidably never read its input. This means memory would grow with each read. Disk writes could be used for storing the list data. All in all, this seems exploitable. Keep in mind that I don't necessarily agree that streams are not copy constructible. Let each class instance decide.

Comment: I'm still not convinced why you can't make a copy of a 'storing' sink of a stream. `myStream(myStream& src){ localstore << src.localstore.str(); }`. StringStream type variables would be perfectly capable of acting that way.

Answer (score 4):

To directly answer the question, you can't copy because the copy constructor for the stringstream class is declared as private.

It was probably declared that way because it seems awkward to copy a stream in most cases, so none of the stream classes have public copy constructors.

Comment: Actually, it's the copy constructor for `ios_base` that is private, which means any stream is uncopyable.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned above you cannot copy stream, but if you need you could copy data:

```
std::stringstream from;
std::stringstream to;

std::copy(std::istream_iterator<char>(from), std::istream_iterator<char>(),
          std::ostream_iterator<char>(to));
```

Comment: why not use s2.str(s1.str()) ?