# Is it possible to "prepare" input from cin?

Tags: c++, redirect, iostream, cin, streambuf

In [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6010864/copying-stringstream/6010930#6010930), specifically in the [linked Ideone example](https://ideone.com/rijov), @Nawaz shows how you can change the buffer object of `cout` to write to something else. This made me think of utilizing that to prepare input from `cin`, by filling its `streambuf`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
        streambuf *coutbuf = cout.rdbuf(cin.rdbuf());
        cout << "this goes to the input stream" << endl;
        string s;
        cin >> s;
        cout.rdbuf(coutbuf);
        cout << "after cour.rdbuf : " << s;
        return 0;
}
```

But this doesn't quite work as expected, or in other words, it fails. :| `cin` still expects user input, instead of reading from the provided `streambuf`. Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Are you asking how to filter `cin`?

Comment: @Gabe: Uhm, nope, I want to provide a prepared input to cin, so it doesn't expect user input but rather reads from the provided content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::stringstream s("32 7.4");
    std::cin.rdbuf(s.rdbuf());

    int i;
    double d;
    if (std::cin >> i >> d)
        std::cout << i << ' ' << d << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Eww, I should've waited 5 min. :(

Comment: @Xeo: I thought the same when I posted :-).

Answer (score 3):

Disregard that question, while further investigating it, I made it work. What I did was actually the other way around than planned; I provided `cin` a `streambuf` to read from instead of filling its own.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
  stringstream ss;
  ss << "Here be prepared input for cin";
  streambuf* cin_buf = cin.rdbuf(ss.rdbuf());
  string s;
  while(cin >> s){
    cout << s << " ";
  }
  cin.rdbuf(cin_buf);
}
```

Though it would still be nice to see if it's possible to provide prepared input without having to change the `cin` `streambuf` directly, aka writing to its buffer directly instead of having it read from a different one.

Comment: Changing the streambuf is the right solution, not trying to modify cin's existing streambuf.