# Redirecting stderr to stdout using string stream

Tags: c++, io, stringstream

I have a code like this

```
int main()
{
    std::stringstream oss;
    std::cerr.rdbuf( oss.rdbuf() );

    std::cerr << "this goes to cerr";
    std::cout << "[" << oss.str() << "]";
}
```

But i get the output of the program as

```
[this goes to cerr]Segmentation fault
```

How does the program segfault?

Comment: Where does `[here's some text]` come from?

Comment: @Prasanth: Please try to post a minimal, compilable and executable example that reproduces the error. Otherwise, we can only guess.

Comment: sorry.. that was the wrong output...

Comment: You are getting the crash with the above posted code?

Comment: yes.. gdb gives this..
(gdb) run

[here's some text]

Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: 13 at address: 0x0000000000000000
0x00007fff80e8c5f8 in std::ostream::flush ()

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to "prepare" input from cin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013638/is-it-possible-to-prepare-input-from-cin)

Comment: Related: freopen() equivalent for c++ streams

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is because you do not restore the buffer of `cerr` before your program exits. Do it like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
  std::stringstream oss;
  std::streambuf* old = std::cerr.rdbuf( oss.rdbuf() );

  std::cerr << "this goes to cerr";
  std::cout << "[" << oss.str() << "]";
  std::cerr.rdbuf(old);
}
```

See [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419356/redirect-stdout-stderr-to-a-string/5419388#5419388) for a solution that is exception safe.

Comment: this works.. thankyou.. although this is just for redirection of cerr to stdout.. it doesnt work for redirecting stderr.. why is that so?

Comment: @Prasanth: It works for redirecting any `iostream` to any other `iostream`, but it requires some minor modifications.

Answer (score 2):

The other answer correctly address the `how does this program segfault` part of your question. However, I feel that the real question `Redirecting stderr to stdout using string stream..` deserves a better answer:

You may simplify the whole shebang and make it scale and perform a infitely better better by just aliasing cerr to cout:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cerr.rdbuf(std::cout.rdbuf());
    std::cerr << "this goes to cerr";
}
```

If you really want to be explicit:

```
    std::cerr.copyfmt(std::cout);
    std::cerr.clear(std::cout.rdstate());
    std::cerr.rdbuf(std::cout.rdbuf());
```

You can verify that the text is actually received on stdout when run