# How do you get the remaining string after a string extracted from a sstream variable?

Tags: c++

Like I have a `stringstream` variable contains `"abc gg   rrr  ff"`

When I use `>>` on that `stringstream` variable, it gives me `"abc"`. How can I get the remaining string: `" gg   rrr  ff"`? It seems neither `str()` nor `rdbuf()` does this work.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can use `std::getline` to get the rest of the string from the stream:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
        stringstream ss("abc gg rrr ff");
        string s1, s2;
        ss >> s1;
        getline(ss, s2); //get rest of the string!
        cout << s1 << endl;
        cout << s2 << endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
abc
gg rrr ff
```

Demo : http://www.ideone.com/R4kfV

There is an overloaded `std::getline` function in which a third parameter takes a delimiter upto which you can read the string. See the documentation of `std::getline`:

- [std::getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/)

Comment: @draw: I can only guess, but maybe it does read in everything through `operator>>` and only stuffs in the whitespace delimiters between the reads? :|

Comment: @draw (and @Xeo): `std::getline` respects the stream behavior. And in stream behaviour you cannot read *same* input more than once. This is what stream means. See my answer here to know what stream means, in detail : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6010864/why-copying-stringstream-is-not-allowed/6010930#6010930

Comment: It works because it does the same thing that `std::getline` does when applied to `std::cout`: starting at the current stream position, read until the delimiter (`\n` by default) or end-of-file.

Comment: Since string may contains '\n', `getline(ss, s2, '\0');`  might be better.

Comment: When doing this with Visual Studio 2017, I actually get a space at the first position of the second string, like " gg rrr ff". I thought that the getline or the ">>" would get rid of that one as well.

Answer (score 32):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str("123 abc");
    int a;
    istringstream is(str);
    is >> a;

    // here we extract a copy of the "remainder"
    string rem(is.str().substr(is.tellg()));

    cout << "Remaining: [" << rem << "]\n";
}
```

Comment: That's the real good answer as it's not subject to eols. It just reads up to the end of the sstream.

Answer (score 10):

```
std::istringstream input;
int extracted;
input >> extracted;
```

IMO, the simplest thing you could possibly do is this:

```
std::stringstream tmp;
tmp << input.rdbuf();
std::string remainder = tmp.str();
```

This is not optimal in terms of performance. Otherwise, directly access the [stringbuffer](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/stringbuf/) (probably using `rbuf().pubseekpos` and `tellg` on the stream... haven't tested that).

Comment: So the `rdbuf()` stores the remaining string?

Comment: rdbuf() _implements_ the buffer for the stream; I believe stores all the data including the already-extracted data. Now, `operator<<` for a `streambuf` is defined in such a way, that it will _do the right thing_ without you having to worry about the stream position.

Answer (score 5):

[`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)

> getline reads characters from an input stream and places them into a string

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, if you need the rest of the string verbatim you can use `std::getline(my_stringstream, result, EOF)` where `result` is a `std::string` containing the result.

Comment: The delimiter can only be a char, and a the actual EOF is not exposed to `getline`, so it will be interpreted as the char `\xff` (the macro EOF is defined as `(-1)`). It would only seem to work if that character is not present in the string.

Answer (score 1):

Keep using `operator>>`, it will extract the rest of it in whitespace-delimited pieces.

Comment: my concern is that I want to leave the white spaces in the remaining string, I'm trying to use substring