# Why does assigning to a reference to std::ostream fail to compile?

Tags: c++, ostream

I am using an abstract class std::ostream. There is the following reference:

```
std::ostream &o = std::cout;
```

If any condition is met I need to initialize o so that the output will be redirected to std::cout. If not, output will be redirected to the file

```
if (!condition)
    o = file; //Not possible
```

How to correctly write the code?

Comment: This problem is more about reseating references than the std::ostream, I would suggest changing the title. Because the question is a good one.

Comment: You need to understand reference in c++ just means an alias. So once the reference has been initialized , any further operator= to it means just change the original item the reference has been referring to. A good example can be found in Steve's answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't reseat a reference.

This is an alternative though :

```
std::ostream &o = (!condition) ? file : std::cout;
```

Answer (score 16):

Either:

```
std::ostream &o = condition ? std::cout : file;
```

or if there's code in between your two snippets:

```
std::ostream *op = &std::cout;
// more code here
if (!condition) {
    op = &file;
}
std::ostream &o = *op;
```

The problem isn't specifically to do with the abstract class, it's that references cannot be reseated.

The meaning of the expression `o = file` isn't "make `o` refer to `file`", it is "copy the value of `file` into the referand of `o`". Luckily for you, `std::ostream` has no `operator=`, and so it fails to compile and `std::cout` isn't modified. But consider what happens with a different type:

```
#include <iostream>

int global_i = 0;

int main() {
    int &o = global_i;
    int file = 1;
    o = file;
    std::cout << global_i << "\n"; // prints 1, global_i has changed
    file = 2;
    std::cout << o << "\n"; // prints 1, o still refers to global_i, not file
}
```

Comment: @Steve: The problem is not only that references cannot be reset, in OP's case `o=file` will not compile also, [because `std::ostream` or any stream in C++ cannot be assigned (or copied).](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6010864/why-copying-stringstream-is-not-allowed/6010930#6010930)

Comment: @Nawaz: I mention that, but IMO it's not a problem. I don't think the questioner actually wants to redirect `stdout` itself to a file, which is the only effect I can think `operator=` would have if it did exist.