# c++ getline compile error when called from function

Tags: c++

// why does this work?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  ifstream inputStream("scores.txt");
  string line;
  getline(inputStream, line);
  cout << line;
  return 0;
}
```

// but this fails with compiler errors.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

ifstream GetStream() {
  ifstream inputStream("scores.txt");
  return inputStream;
}

int main() {
  ifstream inputStream = GetStream();
  string line;
  getline(inputStream, line);
  cout << line;
  return 0;
}
```

compile on mac osx 10.6 w/ g++ 4.2.1

georges-iMac:cs106b george$ g++ help.cpp -o help
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/ios_base.h: In copy constructor ‘std::basic_ios >::basic_ios(const std::basic_ios >&)’:
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/ios_base.h:779: error: ‘std::ios_base::ios_base(const std::ios_base&)’ is private
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/iosfwd:55: error: within this context
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/iosfwd: In copy constructor ‘std::basic_ifstream >::basic_ifstream(const std::basic_ifstream >&)’:
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/iosfwd:89: note: synthesized method ‘std::basic_ios >::basic_ios(const std::basic_ios >&)’ first required here 
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/streambuf: In copy constructor ‘std::basic_filebuf >::basic_filebuf(const std::basic_filebuf >&)’:
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/streambuf:794: error: ‘std::basic_streambuf<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_streambuf(const std::basic_streambuf<_CharT, _Traits>&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]’ is private
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/iosfwd:86: error: within this context
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/iosfwd: In copy constructor ‘std::basic_ifstream >::basic_ifstream(const std::basic_ifstream >&)’:
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/iosfwd:89: note: synthesized method ‘std::basic_filebuf >::basic_filebuf(const std::basic_filebuf >&)’ first required here 
help.cpp: In function ‘std::ifstream GetStream()’:
help.cpp:9: note: synthesized method ‘std::basic_ifstream >::basic_ifstream(const std::basic_ifstream >&)’ first required here

Answer (score 6):

The problem is with this function:

```
ifstream GetStream() {
  ifstream inputStream("scores.txt");
  return inputStream;
}
```

You're returning a *stream* object *by value* which is not allowed, because it requires *copying* of the local object, but you cannot make copy of stream object. Copying of any stream in C++ is **disabled** by having made the copy constructor *private*. Any means ANY, whether it is `stringstream`, `istream`, `ostream`, `iostream` or whatever. Read my post here for the rationale why its disabled:

- [Why copying stringstream is not allowed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6010864/why-copying-stringstream-is-not-allowed)

Now, you may want to return it by *reference*, but you cannot return it by reference also, because `inputStream` is a local object.

---

You may try this:

```
ifstream* GetStream() {
  return new ifstream("scores.txt");
}

int main() {
  ifstream *inputStream = GetStream();
  if ( inputStream && *inputStream )
  {
    string line;
    getline(*inputStream, line);
    cout << line;
  }
  if ( inputStream )
       delete inputStream; 
  return 0;
}
```

But I'm wondering why you would do that. Why not encapsulate everything in a class?

Comment: I would suggest changing `GetStream` to `GetStreamName` and using it as `ifstream inputStream(GetStreamName());` or something, rather than suggesting dynamic allocation.

Comment: @Benjamin: Maybe. I've not worked with smart pointer, so I cannot suggest what I don't know myself much. :-)

Comment: I get it now. Thanks man. Nice read in the supplied link. The example is contrived.

Comment: Think there is a bug/typo in your example:

 return new inputStream("scores.txt");

should read.

 return new ifstream("scores.txt");

Answer (score 2):

Because `GetStream()` invokes implicitly `ifstream`'s copy constructor, which is invalid because one of `ifstream`s base classes has a private copy constructor.

Answer (score 0):

i tested it on my windows computer and everything ran fine, no error's whatsoever. not sure whats going on there.

with regards to the first comment(@Nawaz), the line:

```
ifstream GetStream() {
```

isnt: `ifstream` the return type? so must you return that?