# ifstream return object by reference

Tags: c++

```
//StoreManager.cpp
ifstream&  StoreManager::getDataReaderStream() 
{
        m_dataReader.open(m_dataReaderFileName.c_str(), ios::in | ios::binary);
        return m_dataReader; 
}
//multithread.cpp
void runThread (void *lpData) 
{       
 ifstream ifs1 = storeManager.getDataWriterStream();
 //other code 
}
```

Hi, I am having above class structure

```
ifstream ifs1 = storeManager.getDataWriterStream();
```

i am getting this please help i am not getting this,

```
/usr/include/c++/4.6/fstream: In copy constructor âstd::basic_ifstream<char>::basic_ifstream(const std::basic_ifstream<char>&)â:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/fstream:420:11: note: synthesized method âstd::basic_ios<char>::basic_ios(const std::basic_ios<char>&)â first required here
/usr/include/c++/4.6/streambuf: In copy constructor âstd::basic_filebuf<char>::basic_filebuf(const std::basic_filebuf<char>&)â:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/streambuf:782:7: error: âstd::basic_streambuf<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_streambuf(const __streambuf_type&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_streambuf<_CharT, _Traits>::__streambuf_type = std::basic_streambuf<char>]â is private
/usr/include/c++/4.6/fstream:69:11: error: within this context
/usr/include/c++/4.6/fstream: In copy constructor âstd::basic_ifstream<char>::basic_ifstream(const std::basic_ifstream<char>&)â:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/fstream:420:11: note: synthesized method âstd::basic_filebuf<char>::basic_filebuf(const std::basic_filebuf<char>&)â first required here
multithread.cpp: In member function âvirtual void Multithread::runThread(void*)â:
multithread.cpp:33:57: note: synthesized method âstd::basic_ifstream<char>::basic_ifstream(const std::basic_ifstream<char>&)â first required here
```

Comment: Your line numbers don't match the code you posted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to copy-construct the stream, which cannot be done. You have missed one `&`:

```
ifstream& ifs1 = storeManager.getDataWriterStream();
//------^
```

Comment: See this question/answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6980719/c-getline-compile-error-when-called-from-function?rq=1

Comment: @DwayneTowell The OP's stream is a member of some class, it's not a local, so this will work.

Comment: Right, but it does explain a bit more about why there is a problem rather than just thinking of it as a typo.

Comment: ifstream& ifs1; ifs1 = storeManager.getDataWriterStream();  will it work for this

Comment: @Dipak - no, you cannot leave a reference non-initialized and then later assign a "value" to it. If you _need_ this, use pointers: `ifstream* ifs1 = NULL; /* ... */ ifs1 = &storeManager.getDataWriterStream();` But be careful with the lifetime of `storageManager`.