# Cannot access private member declared in class 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, compiler-errors

Having an issue with this particular method and not sure how to resolve it! The error I'm getting is the above:

> "error C2248: 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>::basic_ios' : cannot
>   access private member declared in class
>   'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>'   C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio 10.0\VC\include\ostream    604"

My method is:

```
ostream operator<<( ostream & stream, ProcessClass const & rhs )
{
  stream << rhs.name_;
  return stream;
}
```

And in the header:

```
friend std::ostream operator<<( std::ostream & stream, ProcessClass const & rhs );
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this? I think it is something to do with passing by reference instead of value... but I'm a bit confused!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The return type should be `ostream &` which is a reference to `ostream`.

```
ostream & operator<<( ostream & stream, ProcessClass const & rhs )
{    //^^^ note this!
  stream << rhs.name_;
  return stream;
}
```

When you return by *value* (instead of *reference*), then that requires copying of stream object, but copying of **any** stream object in C++ has been *disabled* by  having made the copy-constructor<sup>1</sup> `private`.

<sup>1. and copy-assignment as well.</sup>

To know why copying of **any** stream has been disabled, read my detail answer here:

- [Why copying stringstream is not allowed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6010864/why-copying-stringstream-is-not-allowed/6010930#6010930)

Comment: Now the confusing thing is (and I'm not sure what I am missing) is when I change it to above (which I had tried before) I then get an error...


`error C2556: 'std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &,const ProcessClass &)' : overloaded function differs only by return type from 'std::ostream operator <<(std::ostream &,const ProcessClass &)'`


NB. I have slightly modified the code, but go along with the code as above, the error is produced either way upon compilation.

Comment: @Fids: You've defined two times in your class. Why have you defined it two times?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot copy streams, instead return a reference, change to

```
ostream& operator<<( ostream & stream, ProcessClass const & rhs )
```