# C++ stream polymorphy on stack?

Tags: c++, stl, stream, polymorphism, istream

I would like to do something like this:

```
std::wistream input = std::wifstream(text);
if (!input) input = std::wistringstream(text);
// read from input
```

i.e. have text either interpreted as a filename, or, if no such file exists, use its contents instead of the file's contents.

I could of course use `std::wistream * input` and then `new` and `delete` for the actual streams. But then, I would have to encapsulate all of this in a class (constructor and destructor, i.e. proper RAII for exception safety).

Is there another way of doing this on the stack?

Comment: You could use a smart pointer such as auto_ptr to handle the allocation/deallocation automatically, depending of course on your later use of the variable.

Comment: Why on freaking earth would someone want to do this ?

Comment: @Alexandre C.: Because, generally, I want it to work with files, but for testing I also want to just quickly specify some file content sample in the command-line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could abstract the logic that works with `std::wistream& input` into a function of its own, and then call it with a `std::wifstream` or `std::wistringstream` as appropiate.

Answer (score 2):

> I could of course use std::wistream * input and then new and delete for the actual streams. But then, I would have to encapsulate all of this in a class (constructor and destructor, i.e. proper RAII for exception safety).

This is what `std::unique_ptr` is for. Just use `std::unique_ptr<std::istream>`.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there another way of doing this on the stack?

No way.

As the copy-assignment is [disabled for all stream classes in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6010864/why-copying-stringstream-is-not-allowed/6010930#6010930), you cannot use it.That immediately implies that what you want is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered auto_ptr or unique_ptr to manage the wistream pointer?

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/memory/auto_ptr/