# Got error C2280 when using std::vector.push_back()

Tags: c++, vector, ofstream

I got error **"C2280: attempting to reference a deleted function"** compiling error when doing following code:

```
std::ofstream ofs(m_headerFileName, std::ios::binary, std::ios_base::app);
            m_ofsHeader.push_back(ofs);
```

where

```
std::vector<std::ofstream>      m_ofsHeader;
```

I don't understand why I cannot push a `ofstream` instance into an `ofstream` `vector`. Someone gives some hint? Thanks. I am on Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2015.
Also, what is the walkaround here if there is any?

**I am trying to** keep a bunch of ifstream/ofstream with each one having their own file to read/write.

Comment: Streams can not be copied, there can only be one single instance of a stream.

Comment: So what is the workaround?

Comment: You can move stream with c++11.

Comment: It depends, why do you want to do this? What is the actual problem you want to solve with this solution? What is the use-case? Please [read about the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and take some time to reflect how this question could be one.

Comment: why not put pointer (or smart pointer) to stream in vector

Comment: @pm100 Could show a little code example to get me started? Appreciate it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ copy a stream object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7903903/c-copy-a-stream-object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Streams have no copy constructor. You might implement your own or possibly move semantics.

Comment: *"You might implement your own"* - What do you mean? You cannot implement your own copy constructors for standard classes.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Hmmm...driving from stream and overwriting  thing like overflow, underflow, etc...it is gonna be hard but still possible (and by the time of my answer it was not clear what OP wants hence the XY problem occurred)

Answer (score 4):

First of all, the following is wrong, because there is no `std::ofstream` constructor taking three arguments:

> ```
> std::ofstream ofs(m_headerFileName, std::ios::binary, std::ios_base::app);
> ```

You probably meant:

```
std::ofstream ofs(m_headerFileName, std::ios::binary | std::ios::app)
```

And then, there's the storage problem. Streams cannot be copied, that's why your `push_back` fails.

You could just move the streams instead:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <ios>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::ofstream> streams;

    std::ofstream os("foo.txt", std::ios::binary | std::ios::app);
    streams.push_back(std::move(os));
}
```

Note the `std::move`, which casts `os` so that the `&&` overload of `push_back` is used.

Or you store `std::unique_ptr`s to the streams in the vector:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <ios>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<std::ofstream>> streams;

    auto os = std::make_unique<std::ofstream>("foo.txt", std::ios::binary | std::ios::app);
    streams.push_back(std::move(os));
}
```

Comment: Your answer is much better than mine :)

Answer (score 2):

Streams cannot be copied. Their copy constructor and copy assigner are mark as `delete`. Consider using move semantics as well as `std::vector::emplace_back()`:

```
m_ofsHeader.emplace_back(std::move(ofs));
            ^~~~~~~      ^~~~
```