# Make a reference in a method to the stream that I'm reading

Tags: c++, reference, istringstream

I'm in a method, named `total_parsing`, and I create a local variable
`istringstream stream(to_analize)` (where `to_analize` is the string that I have to analyze).

When I reach the special char  `(` or  `[`  I want to claim a method, `reading_between_bracket`, that read the string from the open bracket to the closing bracket. After that I want that the method `reading_between_bracket` give me the possibility to continue the reading in total parsing. I need a method for the reading of string in bracket because I want to claim it recursively every time I reach a bracket. The string is in the format of the example.

Example  `-( B + D -( ( G*F) -H )))`

```
void total_parsing(string to_analize) {
  istrinstream stream(to_analize);
  do {
    // DO OTHER OPERATION WITHOUT BRACKET
    if (token == "(" || !token.find('(')) {
      stream = reading_between_bracket(stream);
    }
  } while (stream >> token);
}

istringstream reading_between_bracket(istringstream stream) {
  // DO THE OPERATION BETWEEN BRACKET
  // RECURSIVE CALL OF THIS METHOD IF I REACH A BRACKET,RETURN THE STREAM
  return stream(or a pointer that make possible to continue reading);
}
```

PS I have to use C++11 and I can utilize STL and sstream.

The code that is in description didn't work

Comment: showing code would be clearer than describing code.

Comment: showing code is guaranteed to match the code, a description of code is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code did not work because passing by value requires making a copy, and [stringstream objects may not be copied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6010864/why-copying-stringstream-is-not-allowed). [See also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7903903/c-copy-a-stream-object).

So instead, pass the stream by reference:

```
void parse(string input){
    istringstream stream(input);
    string token;
    while (stream >> token) {
        if (is_open_bracket(token)) {
            parse_inside_brackets(stream);
        }
    }
}

void parse_inside_brackets(istringstream& stream) {
    // notice the '&'
    // do some processing here; the stream's internal position is updated
    // there is no need to return anything; the change to `stream` will be
    // reflected in the caller
}
```

To accomplish the recursion you describe, you probably want something more like:

```
void parse(string input) { // helper function to set up recursion
    parse_rec(istringstream(input), 0);
}

void parse_rec(istringstream& stream, int level) {
    // 'level' param indicates how many nested brackets we've seen
    string token;
    while (stream >> token) {
        if (is_close_bracket(token) { return; }
        else if (is_open_bracket(token)) {
            parse_rec(stream, level + 1);
        }
        else {
            // handle token at this level
        }
    }
    // If we get here, we ran out of tokens. So if we're not at the base level...
    if (level) {
        // ... then we had an unmatched bracket, so do error handling
    }
}
```

(But it may be the case that you should read up on more sophisticated parsing techniques :) And on the other hand, if you *can* handle the task with this approach, then maybe you don't even need the recursion, just tracking of the indentation level.)

Comment: My problem is to read a operation like this -((((A + B)+ C) + D)*E)  where bracket isn't separated by space

Comment: You will need a more sophisticated approach to *tokenizing* the stream, than simply using `>>`. Hopefully that term will help with your searches ;)