# How to assign ifstream& return from method to variable?

Tags: c++

I have a method name `open_file` declare as below.

```
ifstream& open_file(ifstream &in, const string &filename)
{
    in.close();
    in.clear();

    in.open(filename.c_str());

    return in;
}
```

I want to assign its return value to variable in main() method:

```
int main()
{
    ifstream val1;
    ifstream val2 = open_file(val1, "test.cpp");

    return 0;
}
```

I can't compile the code. My questions are:

1. Can I assign return value from open_file method to variable in main(), and if so how to do that?
2. If I can't assign return value from open_file method to variable, what's the difference if I change its return type to void?

Comment: What you're trying to do, actually? I see, that you pass `val1` by reference, them return it and try to assign it to `val2`..? Also, what's the error description?

Comment: Why return the pass the in reference parameter back out by reference anyways?  If this was an operator, which can be easily chained, I could see it.  Otherwise, any mutations of the in parameter from within the function can be observed outside anyways.

Comment: I try to return val1 back to val2 by reference. I come from C# background, need to understand how c++ copy work.

Comment: @Anonymous: You cannot "copy" streams, so trying to learn about copies in C++ with streams is a non-starter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ifstream val2 = open_file(val1, "test.cpp");
```

This won't compile because it attempts to make a copy of stream object, which is disabled by having made the copy-constructor `private` (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6010864/why-copying-stringstream-is-not-allowed)).

Do this:

```
ifstream & val2 = open_file(val1, "test.cpp");
//val1 and val2 is same here, as val2 is just a reference to val1
```

But then, why would you even do that? You can simply write:

```
open_file(val1, "test.cpp");
//use val1 here - no need to define val2
```

Since the returned value is ignored, it is better if you make the return type `void`. That is less confusing.

Comment: if I change method return type to void, does it has difference? such as it condition state may incorrect.

Comment: @Anonymous: No. In fact, I just edited my answer, suggesting the very same thing.