# why overloading of operator<< must return by reference?

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

I want to print out an object of a user-defined type, like this `cout << ob1;`
so I want to overload operator<< and I want to return by value not by reference but it gives me an error: in two files named : *iosfwd* and *ios_base.h*

```
ostream operator<<( ostream& out, cat& rhs){
    out << rhs.a << ", " << rhs.b << endl;
    return out ; 
}
```

**1)Is it because it  can't create a new ostream object, this is why it have to return by reference ?**

but when I return by reference like this :

```
ostream& operator<<( ostream& out, cat& rhs){
    out << rhs.a << ", " << rhs.b << endl;
    return out ;
}
```

it works fine.
**2)any explanation ?**

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: Also, why would you want to return by value?

Comment: A side note, using endl in your operator makes outputting your type (unexpectedly) flush the iostream. You may want to skip it, or if you _really_ want to output to several lines, output a '\n' instead.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I guess the endl object will work fine, since I did not overload operator<< for type of endl object . no ?

Comment: @AlexDan Yes, there's no problem with using it more than that endl does not just output a line feed, it also flushes the stream which takes quite a bit more time.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the first example, you return a copy of the stream object which is not allowed because the copy-constructors (and copy-assignment as well) of **all** the stream classes in C++ has been disabled by having them made `private`.

Since you cannot make a copy of a stream object, you're required to return it by *reference*, which you're doing in the second example which is why it is working fine.

You may choose to return nothing at all (i.e you can make the return type `void`), but if you do so, then you would not be able to *chain* as `stream << a << b`.  You've to write them separately as `stream <<a` and then `stream << b`.

If you want to know *why* copying of stream objects is disabled, see my answer here:

- [Why copying stringstream is not allowed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6010864/why-copying-stringstream-is-not-allowed)

Answer (score 2):

Streams are non copyable because copying a stream doesn't really make sense, a stream is unique (you can't jump in the same river twice kind of thing). return by value is in C++03 at least copying transaction.

If there are reason you want to return by value, return by reference is the correct version.

Answer (score 0):

It is done to support safe and reasonable operator chaining like

```
    cout<<a<<b;
```

works because of returning a reference.