# Trying to return std::ifstream from a function

Tags: c++

When I try to use this function I get a error at the two returns. If I comment them out I do not get the errors. Is there any reason why this should not work?

```
 std::ifstream bipgetConfigurationPath() {
    char bipacfFilename[256], bipacfFullPath[512];
    char *bipconfigPath;
    char *bipdefaultConfigFile;
    const char *bipdefaultConfigFileName;
    bipdefaultConfigFile = "./Resources/plugins/Xsaitekpanels/D2B_config.txt";
    bipdefaultConfigFileName = "D2B_config.txt";
    XPLMGetNthAircraftModel(0, bipacfFilename, bipacfFullPath);
    bipconfigPath = strstr(bipacfFullPath, bipacfFilename);
    strncpy(bipconfigPath, bipdefaultConfigFileName, sizeof(bipacfFilename));
    puts(bipacfFullPath);

    // Check if ACF-specific configuration exists
    std::ifstream bipcustomStream(bipacfFullPath);
    if (bipcustomStream.good()) {
        return bipcustomStream;
    } else {
        std::ifstream bipdefaultStream(bipdefaultConfigFile);
        if (bipdefaultStream.good()) {
            return bipdefaultStream;
        }

    }
}
```

Thanks Bill

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: any reason you aren't using `std::string`?

Answer (score 6):

All the stream classes in C++ are made noncopyable by having made their copy-constructor `private`. That means, you cannot return stream objects by value. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6010864/why-copying-stringstream-is-not-allowed) for detail. End of the story.

So the solution is to pass a stream object to the function as reference, and open the file in the function, and return from it, or create the stream object using `new` and return the pointer to the stream object from the function, but then if you do so, you've to `delete` the object when you're done with it. I personally would not do either of them.

I will probably encapsulate the stream and the behaviour/work you would like to do with the object, in a class.

In C++11, you can use `std::move` to move the stream object, as streams are movable.

Comment: In C++11, you can return stream object by value since they are movable; this is purely a C++03 limitation.

Comment: Any reason not to recommend `std::move()`? (other than the OP not specifying C++11)

Answer (score 6):

std::streams are not copyable.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said file streams are not copyable. Maybe something more like this:

```
bool bipgetConfigurationPath(std::ifstream& ifs) {

    std::string bipdefaultConfigFileName("D2B_config.txt");

    // ...

    ifs.open(bipdefaultConfigFileName);
    return ifs.good();
}
```