# Why does the return type of a friend function that is overloading the "<<" operator have to be a reference?

Tags: class, c++11, overloading, pass-by-reference, friend

```
friend ostream &operator<<( ostream&, Complex& );
```

Why can't I just use

```
friend ostream operator<<( ostream&, Complex&);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't *have to*, but there are several reasons to explain why this is a common choice.

Many STL classes and objects which deal with streams usually choose the return-by-reference since this allows **chaining**

```
class MyClass {
  public:

  MyClass(int v) : value(v) {}
  int value;

  friend MyClass &operator<<( MyClass&, MyClass& );

};

MyClass &operator<< (MyClass& a, MyClass& b) {
    a.value += b.value;
    return a;
}

int main() {
    MyClass a(2);
    MyClass b(3);
    MyClass c(5);

    a << b << c; // Chaining

    std::cout << a.value; // 10
}
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1933bfe33dacead7)</kbd>

If you were to return by value, this could not be accomplished in a single line

```
a << b; // Can't chain
a << c;
```

Another important reason regarding the abovementioned classes stems from the fact that dealing with streams means **you can't copy a stream** (https://stackoverflow.com/a/6010930/1938163) since it doesn't quite make sense.

And this also means you can't return by value if you're keeping a stream object in the object's state (you'd get an implicitly deleted copy constructor)

```
class MyClass {
  public:

  MyClass(std::string str) {
    ss << str;
  }
  std::stringstream ss; // This CANNOT be copied

  friend MyClass operator<<( MyClass&, MyClass& );

};

MyClass operator<< (MyClass& a, MyClass& b) {
    a.ss << b.ss.str();
    return a; // Can't do this! Copy ctor is implicitly deleted due to ss
}
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/87d06fda975857b6)</kbd>

In this latter, common case returning by reference is almost a must.

Aside from these cases nobody forces you to return by reference though. It also depends on your use case and, more importantly, **on how your object manages its resources** (remember that there might be a destructor involved if you return by value if there's no [RVO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) involved).

Answer (score 1):

Return by value means the object needs to be copied, otherwise it might not be valid, which for streams can pose problems as the original (source of the copy) object might cleanup after itself when his destructor is called. Returning by reference avoids this and, what's more important, chained calls will share the same `ostream` instead of a new stream after each `<<` call.

Answer (score 1):

`std::ostream` explicitly blocks your ability to copy it. Note that it has a deleted copy constructor.

Therefore, if you tried to return it by value, it would cause a compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a strict requirement. If you use the non-reference version,

```
ostream << a << b << c
```

will copy the ostream object for each invocation of the operator << when it returns. There is probably no reason that you would want a copy rather than the original ostream object.