# Convert get_word into function, don't understand instructions?

Tags: c++

I'm following these guidelines for a little project in school but am unclear on how to implement this into a separate function? Any suggestions?

I don't want anyone to write code for me, but a little hint would be helpful! :D My below code does exactly what I think these instructions are asking, but just not in a separate function.

I think I declared the prototype correctly but man am I really stumped! Also, what exactly is the "command line"?

*get_word: The first function should be called "get_word". It takes two arguments. Every call to this function will fill one of the arguments with a word from the file. You should then output every word you receive and a count of the total number of words to a file specified by the user on the command line. This function doesn't return anything.*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

//void get_word(std::ifstream, std::string);

int main()
{
  std::ifstream word("io_file.txt");

  std::string str1;
  int counter = 0;

  while(word >> str1)
    {
      std::cout << str1 << '\n';
      ++counter;
    }
  std::cout << "Word count: " << counter << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Move the code that does the input in your main into your get_word function. You will also need to use reference parameters.

Comment: Well if I understand correctly, the only line that actually does input is "while(word >> str1)". I'm a little confused about the command line part. For example, I pass two files in the command line to the program before it starts, one being an input file and another an output file, but I'm already reading from a file within the program! How can I read from two files?

Comment: "Well if I understand correctly, the only line that actually does input is "while(word >> str1)"." - Yes.The number of files is not an issue here.

Answer (score 0):

> "get_word". It takes two arguments. Every call to this function will
>   fill one of the arguments with a word from the file.

As you supposed, you will need two arguments, one file and one string.
But because you must fill the string passed as argument with a word from the file, you have to declare the string argument as reference.
What it means ? By default, arguments are passed as copy, for example

```
void plusTwo(int a) { a += 2 }
```

The code inside the function declaration will modify the copy of the variable passed as parameter, so :

```
int b = 0;
plusTwo(b);
//b still equals 0
```

So you have to mark the argument with an `&` in the declaration which means that you passed the argument as reference (no copy). So for example :

```
void plusTwo(int &a) { a += 2 }
```

The code inside the function declaration will modify the copy of the variable passed as parameter, so :

```
int b = 0;
plusTwo(b);
//b equals now 2
```

So the correct prototype is :

```
void get_word(std::ifstream, std::string&);
```

Then, the command line is the window where are displayed the text with "cout". So in order to get the file path, you have to do :

```
std::string filePath;
cin >> filePath;
```

filePath will get what is entered by user.

Comment: `void get_word(std::ifstream, std::string&);` -> `void get_word(std::ifstream &, std::string&);` Cannot copy an `ifstream`, [or any stream for that matter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6010864/why-copying-stringstream-is-not-allowed), so you can't pass it by value.

Comment: Why can't a stream be copied if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: @Inert Because it doesn't make sense to do so - there is really only one stream. In the same way it wouldn't make any sense for a bank account object to be copied - there is only one bank account with a specific account number. Preventing the copy is done by deleting the copy constructor.

Comment: Ahh, that makes more sense! Thanks for the reply!