# Using stringstream object multiple times

Tags: c++, stringstream

I am finding it difficult to wrap my head around working of `stringstream`. Why the second while loop in the below code does not work? If stream object is getting emptied at the end of the first while loop is there any workaround to restore it back to initial condition?

```
// input is string of numbers separated by spaces (eg. "22 1 2 4")
    std::string input;
    std::getline(std::cin, input); 

    stringstream stream (input);

    // print individual numbers
    while (stream >> n)
    {
        cout << n << endl;
    }

    // print individual numbers again
    while (stream >> n)
    {
        cout << n << endl;
    }
```

Comment: What do `input` & `std::cin` have to do with the two loops?

Comment: And where is `stream` declared?

Comment: Anyway, you can see that the stream _must_ be emptied by the first loop, otherwise the loop would never finish. In fact, if the stream didn't advance past tokens as they're extracted, you'd have an infinite loop always returning the first item.

Comment: sorry, updated the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stringstream` is a subclass of `istream`, so `stream >> n` (`std::istream::operator>>`) returns a `reference to istream`

`stream` can be converted to `bool` (`std::ios::operator bool`): it converts to `false` when it no longer has any data (reached end-of-file)

You have finished reading `stream` in your first loop - it no longer has any data.

> If stream object is getting emptied at the end of the first while loop is there any workaround to restore it back to initial condition?

You need to store values on your own and then reuse them - copying streams is not allowed (it doesn't make sense for them really) - [Why copying stringstream is not allowed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6010864/why-copying-stringstream-is-not-allowed/6010930#6010930)

Answer (score 2):

It's not emptied, but once you reach the end, you're stuck at the end – just like with other streams.

You need to clear the error flags (`stream.clear()`) and then either rewind (`stream.seekg(0)`) or reset the input string (`stream.str(input)`).

Comment: In the existing code, `failbit` will also be set because it tries to read again after eof is reached. Calling `seekg` does _not_ reset that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the `stringstream` first, in order to make multiple passes over what you have read into `input`. `input` itself is just a `string` not `stream`. `#include <sstream>` and then after reading `input` create the `stringstream` with:

```
std::stringstream stream (input);
```

You can then read with your first `while` loop, but the second `while` will not work because the stream position is left at the end of the stringsteam after the first `while` and `eofbit` is set.

You need call `stream.seekg(0)` to "rewind" the file and clear `eofbit`, see: [std::basic_istream::seekg](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg) before the second `while` loop.